# Django Update and CreateView using the same Crispy Form, Add view Error

Tags: python, django

I'm using the same crispy form for add and edit and have added a variable to so I can change the submit button text from add to edit and vice versa.

However the add view is coming up with the below error:

```
Traceback: (removed the in built references) 

...

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in dispatch
  954.         return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

...

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in get_context_data
  969.         context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_context_data
  93.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  45.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /sites/site/add_subnet/7
Exception Value: 'SubnetForm' object is not callable
```

im not sure as to why as the code for the form looks good to my unskilled eyes at least anyway

forms.py:

```
class SubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteSubnets
        fields = ['subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'device_data', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        super(SubnetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['circuit'].queryset = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data=site_id)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'subnet_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Add Subnet' if self.is_add else 'Edit Subnet', css_class='btn-primary'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(    
                Div(
                    Field('subnet', placeholder='Subnet'),
                    Div('subnet_type', title="Subnet Type"),
                    css_class='col-lg-3'
                ),
                Div(
                    Div('circuit', title='Circuit'),
                    Div('device_data', title="Device Data"),
                    css_class='col-lg-3'
                ),
                Div(
                    Field('vlan_id', placeholder='VLAN ID'),
                    Field('peer_desc', placeholder="Peer Description"),
                    css_class='col-lg-3'
                ),
            css_class='row'
            )
        )
```

Views:

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    form_class = SubnetForm(is_add=True)
    template_name = "sites/subnet_form.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args=(self.site_id,))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.site_data = self.site
        return super(AddSubnet, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['site_id'] = self.site_id
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.site_id
        context['SiteName']=self.site.location
        context['FormType']='Add'
        context['active_subnets']='class="active"'

        return context

class EditSubnet(UpdateView):
    model = SiteSubnets
    form_class = SubnetForm
    template_name = "sites/subnet_form.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.edit_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(EditSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args=(self.site_id,))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.site_data = self.object.site_data
        return super(EditSubnet, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.site_id
        context['SiteName']=self.site.location
        context['FormType']='Edit'
        context['active_subnets']='class="active"'

        return context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the culprit: `form_class = SubnetForm(is_add=True)`. `form_class` is supposed to be what the name indicates, just the `class`, not an instance. Use `get_form_kwargs` to add initialization parameters to the form constructor call (as you already do with `site_id`):

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    form_class = SubnetForm   # just the form CLASS
    # ...

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['is_add'] = True  # you can set 'is_add' here
        kwargs['site_id'] = self.site_id
        return kwargs
```